# What version of sqlite does iOS provide?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

What version of Sqlite does iOS include?

Comment: I really interested in iOS 8.0 and iOS 8.1 SQLite versions because of this news: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/90549

Comment: I got 3.7.13 : 3007013 on console. How to switch to latest version of SQLite?

Comment: @k06a that link is no longer valid. Do you recall what "this news" was, that made you interested in iOS 8.0 and 8.1 SQLite versions?

Comment: @Syclone0044 here is cached version of this page: https://web.archive.org/web/20150228085642/http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/90549 "The latest SQLite 3.8.7 alpha version is 50% faster than the 3.7.17 release from 16 months ago."

Comment: You may query & print the sqlite version, answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47296824/342794

Answer (score 43):

[This wiki](https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase/wiki/SQLite-version-(bundled-with-OS)) has the latest list:

| iOS Version | SQLite Version |
| --- | --- |
| 2.2 | 3.4.0 |
| 3.1.3 | 3.6.12 |
| 4.0.2 | 3.6.22 |
| 4.1.0 | 3.6.23.2 |
| 4.2.0 | 3.6.23.2 |
| 5.1.1 | 3.7.7 |
| 6.0.1 | 3.7.13 |
| 7.0 | 3.7.13 |
| 7.0.6 | 3.7.13 |
| 8.0.2 | 3.7.13 |
| 8.2 | 3.8.5 |
| 9.0 | 3.8.8 |
| 9.3.1 | 3.8.10.2 |
| 10.0 beta 2 | 3.13.0 |
| 10.0 GM | 3.14.0 |
| 10.2 | 3.14.0 |
| 10.3.1 | 3.16.0 |
| 11.0 | 3.19.3 |
| 12.0 | 3.24.0 |
| 12.1 | 3.24.0 |
| 13.1.3 | 3.28.0 |
| 14.1 | 3.32.3 |
| 14.2 | 3.32.3 |
| 14.4 | 3.32.3 |
| 14.5 | 3.32.3 |
| 14.8 | 3.32.3 |
| 15.0 | 3.36.0 |
| 15.1 | 3.36.0 |
| 15.2 | 3.36.0 |
| 15.4.1 | 3.37.0 |
| 15.6.1 | 3.37.0 |
| 16.0 | 3.39.0 |
| 16.0.3 | 3.39.0 |
| 16.5.2 | 3.39.5 |

| macOS Version | SQLite Version |
| --- | --- |
| 10.9 | 3.7.13 |
| 10.10 | 3.8.5 |
| 10.10.3 | 3.8.5 |
| 10.11 | 3.8.10.2 |
| 10.12 | 3.14.0 |
| 10.13 | 3.19.3 |
| 10.14.2 | 3.24.0 |
| 12.4 | 3.37.0 |
| 12.5 | 3.37.0 |
| 12.6 | 3.37.0 |
| 13.2 | 3.39.5 |

Answer (score 12):

Using SELECT sqlite_version() on various iOS versions:

From the internets:

```
2.2: 3.4.0
3.1.3: 3.6.12
4.0.2: 3.6.22
4.1.0: 3.6.23.2
4.2.0: 3.6.23.2
```

I just tested now:

```
6.0.1: 3.7.13
```

Comment: For an additional data point, 5.1.1 uses SQLite 3.7.7. And, as an aside, the function name is `sqlite3_version()`.

Comment: Anyone checked IOS 7 yet?

Comment: iOS 8.2 has upgraded sqlite3 to 3.8.5 (Until then it stayed at 3.7.13)

Answer (score 10):

I've just checked on the iOS 7:

```
7.0: 3.7.13
```

Comment: No change since 6.0, even in the latest 7.0.6 version.

Comment: Even in the latest iOS 7.1.2 (latest for iPhone4), it is still 3.7.13.

Answer (score 7):

Just do:

```
p (const char*) sqlite3_libversion()
```

in a debugger running an app (that links to the sqlite lib) on a device on which you want to know the sqlite version.

On an iOS 8.0.2 iPhone 5s I get 3.7.13 so it seems they haven't changed version in a while based on reports in the other answers that version 6.0 used the same version.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite has been updated in iOS 8.2 to version `3.8.5`

Answer (score 2):

Use following to printout the version in your code. You may define following as a separate debug only function and call it from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your appDelegate.

```
#if DEBUG
// Int representing version; e.g. "3016000" for macOS 10.12.4
int sqliteVersion = sqlite3_libversion_number();
NSLog(@"Sqlite Version: %d", sqliteVersion);

// String representing version; e.g. "3.19.3" for iOS 11
const char *sqliteLibVersion = sqlite3_libversion();
NSString *sqliteLibVersionStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqliteLibVersion];
NSLog(@"Sqlite Lib Version: %@", sqliteLibVersionStr);

// String representing sourceId; e.g. "2017-06-27 16:48:08 2b09...2e2377b" on iOS11
const char *sqliteSourceid = sqlite3_sourceid();
NSString *sqliteSourceidStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqliteSourceid];
NSLog(@"Sqlite SourceID: %@", sqliteSourceidStr);
#endif
```

Alternatively, look at `sqlite3.h` directly in Xcode. For iOS 11:

```
#define SQLITE_VERSION        "3.19.3"
#define SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER 3019003
#define SQLITE_SOURCE_ID      "2017-06-27 16:48:08 2b09...2e2377b"
```

`sqlite3.h` also has other methods that can be used for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Update Nov 2020 with iOS 14

```
  ╔═════════════╦════════════════╗
  ║ iOS Version ║ SQLite Version ║
  ╠═════════════╬════════════════╣
  ║ 13.1.3      ║ 3.28.0         ║
  ╠═════════════╬════════════════╣
  ║ 14.1        ║ 3.32.3         ║
  ╚═════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9.0 the SQLite version is `3.8.10.2`