# Different sqlite3 database engines shipped with different iOS versions?

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

There's a strange behavior if I run a datamodel in SQLite3 on a simulator/real iOS device below iOS 13.1:

```
create view xyz
as
with x as
(
  select y from z;
)
select x.y, x1.a from x, x1 where...
```

Running a database with any of such a view which begins with a "with" clause, causes the app to crah with "malformed database scheme" on the view "xyz".

If I run the same database on a device with iOS => 13.1 anything is okay.

I don't understand what happens. I thought the included sqlite3 library is always the same Xcode compiles into the app? Isn't it?

If I didn't know better, I would say devices below iOS 13 were shipped with an older Sqlote3 library which doesn't recognize a view with a syntax mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Your app runs with the SQLite version that ships with the operating system. And it varies. See [What version of sqlite does iOS provide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288128/what-version-of-sqlite-does-ios-provide)